# How can i check for a character after certain text within a listbox?

Tags: vb.net, search, listbox

How can i check for a character after other text within a listbox?

e.g
Listbox contents:

`Key1: V`

`Key2: F`

`Key3: S`

`Key4: H`

How do I find what comes after Key1-4:?

Key1-4 will always be the same however what comes after that will be user defined.

I figured out how to save checkboxes as theres only 2 values to choose from, although user defined textboxes is what im struggling with. (I have searched for solutions but none seemed to work for me)

Usage:

```
    Form1_Load
    If ListBox1.Items.Contains("Key1: " & UsersKey) Then
            TextBox1.Text = UsersKey
        End If
```

Which `textbox1.text` would then contain `V` / whatever the user defined.

I did try something that kind of worked:

```
    Form1_Load
    Dim UsersKey as string = "V"
    If ListBox1.Items.Contains("Key1: " & UsersKey) Then
            TextBox1.Text = UsersKey
        End If
```

but i'm not sure how to add additional letters / numbers to `"V"`, then output that specific number/letter to the textbox. (I have special characters blocked)

Reasoning I need this is because I have created a custom save settings which saves on exit and loads with form1 as the built in save settings doesn't have much customization.
e.g Can't choose save path, when filename is changed a new user.config is generated along with old settings lost.

Comment: check my answer - you don't need to over-complicate things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple keys, I assume you have multiple textboxes to display the results?

Then something like this would work. Loop thru the total number of keys, inside that you loop thru the alphabet. When you find a match, output to the correct textbox:

```
    Dim UsersKey As String
    For i As Integer = 1 To 4
        For Each c In "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
            UsersKey = c
            If ListBox1.Items.Contains("Key" & i & ": " & UsersKey) Then
                Select Case i
                    Case 1
                        TextBox1.Text = UsersKey
                    Case 2
                        TextBox2.Text = UsersKey
                    Case 3
                        TextBox3.Text = UsersKey
                    Case 4
                        TextBox4.Text = UsersKey
                End Select
                Exit For 'match found so exit inner loop
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Also, you say your settings are lost when the filename is changed. I assume when the version changes? The Settings has an upgrade method to read from a previous version. If you add an `UpgradeSettings` boolean option and set it to True and then do this at the start of your app, it will load the settings from a previous version:

```
    If My.Settings.UpgradeSettings = True Then
        My.Settings.Upgrade()
        My.Settings.Reload()
        My.Settings.UpgradeSettings = False
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
```

Updated Answer:

Instead of using a listtbox, read the settings file line by line and output the results to the correct textbox based on the key...something like this:

```
        Dim settingsFile As String = "C:\settings.txt"
        If IO.File.Exists(settingsFile) Then
            For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadLines(settingsFile)
                Dim params() As String = Split(line, ":")
                If params.Length = 2 Then
                    params(0) = params(0).Trim
                    params(1) = params(1).Trim
                    Select Case params(0)
                        Case "Key1"
                            Textbox1.Text = params(1)
                        Case "Key2"
                            Textbox2.Text = params(1)
                    End Select
                End If
            Next line
        End If
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly!  Yes I had multiple textboxes for various keybinds so you saved me some time with the cases as I was doing it a different method.  For the settings, I never actually changed the version within the project settings as the program is not yet complete, it's been a while since I used the included settings as I started working on other things but from what I remember each time the file name was changed the settings would create a new folder with the new filename, and therefore there would be no settings stored, perhaps your upgrade method would fix this, but either

Comment: But either way I would prefer having a custom save destination so thanks again for your help!

Comment: It it only possible to find one character?  I have four text boxes, two ranges from 1-10, and the other two ranges from 40-500, is it possible to also load these values?  I added `0123456789` to the above character list.  I attempted it but when the textbox exceeds 1 character it doesn't load the value.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you explain it better?

Comment: Yes, lets say `textbox1.text = "500"`, then in `listbox1` it would appear as `Value1: 500`  When the value is two or more digits it doesn't seem to load, but if it's one digit or one letter it will load perfectly fine, although if possible I will need it to load the three digits would could range anywhere between 1 to 500

Comment: The numbers in the textboxes are values from Trackbars, once the trackbar changes value the textbox also gets updated, so while loading the textbox value with the form it would also set the value on the trackbar to whatever the user saved it as.

Comment: So to clarify, your textboxes get assigned values from trackbars. When the program closes, you save those values using some custom settings. Then when you run the program again, you want to load those same values back into the textboxes, correct? What is the listbox for?

Comment: Yes, these specific textboxes get assigned values from the trackbar, the only purpose of this is to tell the user what value the trackbar is currently set to.  The custom settings I referred to, when the program is closing it will check all of the values and then add them to the listbox, which the listbox will save that list to a textfile. Then when the program loads, the textfile will be printed into the listbox, after that happens it will then set all the values from the listbox which comes from the saved textfile.

Comment: The original post was for keybinds/shortcuts, now i'm attempting to save values of items.
The above comments, `Value1: 500` could be 500 different numbers, depending what the user sets them to. `Value1:` could also be saved as `Value:1 Textbox1.text` or `Value:1 trackbar1.value`, although i'm not having an issue with saving the settings.  The issue i'm having is, the list box is reading the correct value, but `Userskey` is only looking for one character / digit, which the setting could be either 1, 2 or 3 digits in length.  When it's 2 or 3 digits in length it will not load that

Comment: specific setting, when it's one digit it will load without problems.  The only purpose of the listbox is to save the settings, it will not be visible to the user.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem!

Comment: @Joey *"The only purpose of the listbox is to save the settings, it will not be visible to the user"* -- this doesn't sound right. Why list box and not `List (Of T)` ??

Answer (score 2):

Look at regular expressions for this.

Using the keys from your sample:

```
Dim keys As String = "VFSH"
Dim exp As New RegEx("Key[1-4]: ([" & keys& "])")
For Each item As String in ListBox1.Items
    Dim result = exp.Match(item)
    If result.Success Then
        TextBox1.Text = result.Groups(1).Value
    End If
Next
```

It's not clear to me how your ListBoxes work. If you might find, for example, "`Key 2:`" inside ListBox1 that you need to ignore, you will want to change the `[1-4]` part of the expression to be more specific.

Additionally, if you're just trying to exclude unicode or punctuation, you could also go with ranges:

```
Dim keys As String = "A-Za-z0-9"
```

If you are supporting a broader set of characters, there are some you must be careful with: `]`, `\`, `^`, and `-` can all have special meanings inside of a regular expression character class.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to test your answer as I was already configuring the answer from Chase which worked, thank you for trying anyways though, I should've updated the post sooner to let everyone know it was solved.

Comment: @Joey Just keep in mind - some answers here a bogus, questionable, or inefficient solutions, even if they have positive score

Answer (score 0):

You can associate text box with a key via its `Name` or `Tag` property. Lets say you use Name. In this case `TextBox2` is associated with `key2`. `TextBox[N] <-> Key[N]`

Using this principle the code will look like this [considering that your list item is string]

```
Sub Test()

    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return

    Dim data[] As String = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, string).Split(new char(){":"})

    Dim key As String = data(0).Substring(3) 
    Dim val As String = data(1).Trim() 

    ' you can use one of the known techniques to get control on which your texbox sits. 
    ' I omit this step and assume "Surface1" being a control on which your text boxes sit

     DirectCast(
         (From ctrl In Surface1.Controls 
         Where ctrl.Name = "TextBox" & key
         Select ctrl).First()), TextBox).Text = val

End Sub
```

As you can see, using principle I just explained, you have little parsing and what is important, there is no growing `Select case` if, lets say, you get 20 text boxes. You can add as many text boxes and as many corresponding list items as you wish, the code need not change.